# Linking errors on mac using xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, linker, dylib

I'm currently porting a program to run on MacOS but I'm having trouble linking two dynamic libraries, namely the Bullet physics library and tinyXML, although I imagine there's some problem not specific to those libraries that's causing my issues.

I've built bullet from the command line make file, both as raw dylibs and as a framework (although I can't find where it puts that framework and the framework doesn't show up when I add it via 'Linked frameworks and libraries'). I've built tinyXML from command line and the supplied xCode project, with the same linker error results both times.

I've tried adding the raw dylibs, although when made using 'sudo make install', they end up in 'usr/local/lib', which doesn't seem to make them visible to the list of libraries, meaning I need to use the 'Add Other'. 'usr/local/lib' is a hidden folder, so that means pressing '⌘ + shift + .'

I can then locate the relevant libraries and link them but, unfortunately, still get a bunch of linker errors as if I hadn't linked them at all.

I'm building the libraries for 64bit x86, same as my program. I've read that there are some issues regarding which version of the standard library the dylibs are built against matters, but I can't find any options for that in the project settings.

So, to recap: is there anything obvious that I'm missing, why when I build and install a library (e.g. sudo make install) does this library not appear in xcode when trying to add dependent libraries? What additional steps need to be taken to raise these self built libraries to that status?

Also, when linking the libraries directly by navigating to 'usr/local/lib', why am I still getting linker errors?